# Equivalences and flipping

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are the following equivalences correct? Or should the inequalities be flipped somewhere?

$$ -x+1 \le -(-3+4x-x^2)^{1/3} \iff  -(x-1) \le -(-3+4x-x^2)^{1/3} \iff  (-3+4x-x^2)^{1/3} \le (x-1)$$

Comment: You're correct. What made you question it?

Comment: If multiplying by negatives worries you, then try using subtraction and addition instead.  $a\leq b$ and then subtract both sides by $a+b$ to get $a-(a+b)\leq b-(a+b)$ which when simplified gives $-b\leq -a$

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was correct too, and it looks correct to me. When I input the first two inequalities into mathematica I get True. When I input the last two inequalities like this `Equivalent[-(x - 1) <= -(-3 + 4*x - x^2)^(1/3), (-3 + 4*x - x^2)^(1/3) <= (x - 1)]` I get output not True, but 
`1 - x <= -(-3 + 4 x - x^2)^(1/3) \iff (-3 + 4 x - x^2)^(1/3) <= -1 + x`  which I'm not sure how to interpret. Is it saying that it's in fact equivalent?

Comment: Ah, yes now I see that the mathematica output of the last two inequalities are indeed equal, I'm just getting tired.

Comment: Just noting that I think I wrongly used the Equivalent functions. Rather, it should be `ineq1 = 2 x + 1 > 3;
ineq2 = x > 1;
Simplify[ineq1 == ineq2]` which returns True in this case.